# Why does my ArrayList show size of zero when logged from main method but shows a size of a certain number when called from internal method?

Tags: java, android, firebase, arraylist

I am creating a Vending Machine program using firebase where everytime a value is updated in the firebase it gets extracted to class "NewUt" and gets added to the ArrayList "allLocations".I have Log.d() in the onCreate method that prints the size of the array and another Log.d() in the onDataChange method when the data is updated. The Log.d() in the onCreate shows that the Array has a size of 0 but the Log.d() in the onDataChange method shows a size more than zero. What could be the problem?

I have tried to put the onDataChange inside a different method but still same results.

```
package com.xeon.vendingmachine;

import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Camera;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;

public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements 
OnMapReadyCallback {

private GoogleMap mMap;
DatabaseReference myRef;
private static ArrayList<Utilities> allLocations = new ArrayList<>();




@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
    FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this);
    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    myRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Vending Machines");
    Random r = new Random();
    Double randLat = r.nextDouble()*100;
    Double randLon = r.nextDouble()*100;
   Utilities utilitiesForDatabase = new Utilities(randLat,randLon,"Carol Machifne","Carfol","Layfs","Ffull");
     String uid = myRef.push().getKey();
     myRef.child(uid).setValue(utilitiesForDatabase);
    String TAG  = "RefFromMain";
   myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            allLocations.clear();

            for (DataSnapshot allLocs : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                Utilities newUt = allLocs.getValue(Utilities.class);
                allLocations.add(newUt);
            }


            Log.d("ArraySize" , "Size is " + allLocations.size());
            Log.d("LatLng" , " New Lattitude : " + allLocations.get(allLocations.size()-1).getLattitude() + " Longitude : " + allLocations.get(allLocations.size()-1).getLongitude());
             NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilderArray =
                    new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext())
                            .setContentTitle("New location added")
                            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.common_google_signin_btn_icon_dark)
                            .setContentText("Size is " + allLocations.size());

            NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            mNotificationManager.notify(1,mBuilderArray.build());

        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Log.e("Database Error", "The data could not be extracted");
        }
    });
    Log.d(TAG , "Size is " + this.allLocations.size());

}


@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {

    mMap = googleMap;



}


}
```

Log.d() in the onCreate method.

```
D/RefFromMain: Size is 0
D/RefFromMain: Size is 0
D/RefFromMain: Size is 0
D/RefFromMain: Size is 0
```

Log.d() in the onDataChange method.

```
D/ArraySize: Size is 4
D/ArraySize: Size is 5
D/ArraySize: Size is 6
D/ArraySize: Size is 10
```

Answer (score 4):

```
 allLocations = new ArrayList<>();
 Log.d(TAG , "Size is " + allLocations.size());
```

There's nothing in it yet. Its size is therefore zero.

Later you put something in it:

```
          allLocations.add(newUt);
        }
        Log.d("ArraySize" , "Size is " + allLocations.size());
```

Now its size has increased (by some number of elements depending on the immediately-preceding for-loop)

Answer (score 2):

You logged the array size in main after allocation. So it is 0. 
But in `onDataChange` you have put data in that array with `allLocations.add(newUt);`. So it is showing the size equal to the number of data inserted in it.

Comment: So, how can I programme it in a way that when the array is populated in onDataChange it is also populated in onCreate?

Comment: Do you want to save the data in array list after it is loaded once?

Comment: If you want like i said in previous comment then you need to make the array list static and allocate memory outside the onCreate method. 
like

`provate static ArrayList<Utilities> allLocations = new ArrayList<>();`

and drop this line from on create 

` allLocations = new ArrayList<>();`

and drop this line from `onDataChanged` 

`allLocations.clear();`

Comment: So I want it so that the array only contains the updated values from onDataChange() method and I want to make it so I can use the data from the array from anywhere in the class.

Comment: To get what you want, you have to do same as I have stated in the last comment. EXCEPT, you should keep the `allLocations.clear();` in the method `onDataChanged'.

Comment: I did exactly what you said but now what it’s doing is that it is keeping the previously updated data and adding the new updated data to it.

Comment: please don't remove `allLocations.clear();` if you want only update data.

Comment: I didn’t remove it

Comment: I've updated my code as you suggested. But, unfortunately, I am receiving the same results.

Comment: this is very unfortunate neel. kindly try debugging to get insight of what is happening there. [How to debug in android studio](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/)

Answer (score 0):

At first you are initialling your Arraylist. here

```
 allLocations = new ArrayList<>();
    Log.d(TAG , "Size is " + allLocations.size());
```

So it initialling with empty data . there's nothing in it . After that in `addValueEventListener` you are adding data to your `allLocations` ArrayList.

```
 myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {

        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            allLocations.clear();
            for (DataSnapshot allLocs : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                Utilities newUt = allLocs.getValue(Utilities.class);
              allLocations.add(newUt);
            }
```

So now it has values  in it .

Comment: so is there any way to program it so both of the results are the same?

Comment: @NeelPatel Err, print the size after the method calls?

Comment: yes. otherwise if you have data before that `addValueEventListener` you can add manually also . by `allLocations.add("your data")`

Comment: addValueEvenetListener is the main reason I have created the array so I can add all of the updated data in the array. Is there any way so that the updated data is added in the array and when the array is called from anywhere in the class it actually shows the data?

Comment: ` the updated data is added in the array ` : You are adding data to your arraylist properly . Now when you use it . check if arraylist is not  empty then use it

Comment: that's the problem. I actually need it to not be empty at any given time.

Comment: then first add values to it then use it .

Comment: I want the data from the addValueEventListener to be added to the array. And then from another method, I need to use the array to add markers to a map. But when I do that it shows an error that the array is empty.

Comment: then you need to change the sequence of code  execution .  You need to write `addValueEventListener` code before that method  .

Comment: before the onCreate method?

Comment: no before onCreate it will cause a error . use before that method you are using that arraylist in

Comment: the addEventValueListener is in the onCreate method and it is before the method that is trying to use the array.

Comment: show the method in which you are trying to access that list

Comment: I put it in my questions code. Its at the very bottom. It's called onMapReady().

Comment: I don't understand your use case in detail (I don't know what a 'firebase is), but it seems to boil down to this: (a) add the data when it's first available to you, and (b) don't clear the list.

Comment: @another-dave i've tried my best to solved his problem . but without code and flow cant do much

Comment: I have updated the code in my questions. Can you please take a look at it and suggest me a solution? Thanks!

Comment: @NeelPatel so you want to generate notification when `onDataChange` called  ?

Comment: I want it so when I call the array size from the main method it actually shows the correct size.

Comment: @NeelPatel lets continue discusion in [chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187620/arraylist-size)